# WPF Filter Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, filtering, xelement

I have a datagrid that I want to filter based on a value selected from a combobox. The source of the datagrid is an XML file. Below is the code I am using. When I trace the code the view filter is returning true and false correctly for each row but the datagrid never updates. What simple thing am I missing?

```
ComboBoxItem typeItem = (ComboBoxItem)cbPositionFilter.SelectedItem;
String position = typeItem.Content.ToString();

IEnumerable<XElement> playersSource = ((XContainer)AllPlayers.DataContext).Descendants("Player");
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(playersSource);

 view.Filter = delegate(object item)
 {
       bool match = ((XElement)(item)).Element("position").Value == position;
       return match;
 };
```

Comment: What XAML are you using to bind the XML to the grid? I suspect the bound collection and playersSource are different and therefore have different default views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `DataGrid` bound to `playersSource`, or `view`? If you're doing the former, try the latter. :)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't realizing I need to REbind the datagrid after setting up the view + filter. Thanks so much!